# Aggregating results of vectors based on Omnet++ signals

Tags: omnet++

I want to compute an overall delivery ratio in function of time using vectors based on Omnet++ signals ? How can i achieve it when there is a multiple source and only one sink.

For example, say that i have 10 mobiles nodes that send data to a fixed AP, the delivery ratio is equal to (received/sent packets), but the AP knows only the amount of received packets.

I declared the following signals and statistics:

For AP:

```
@signal[receivedBndl](type = "int");
@statistic[receivedBundle](title="ReceivedBundle";source=receivedBndl;record=count,mean,last,vector);
```

For Nodes:

```
@signal[sentBndl](type = "int");
@statistic[sentBundle](title="SentBundle";source=sentBndl;record=count,mean,last,vector);
```

Is it possible to create another @statistics that compute the Delivery Ratio in function of time with this 2 signals ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more like a network wide statistic, than something related to a single node so you have to install your statistic listeners on the top-level network module itself instead of the actual nodes. OMNeT++ signals propagate up on the containment chain so any signal that was sent to a specific node will be delivered also to the containing network module. This makes it possible to install the statistics on the network and get the given signal there (too).

To achieve this I would rewrite the code to actually emit the sent/received cPacket objects (and not the count of them as an integer). You still can count the number of packets using the count() function in the statistics.

For AP:

```
@signal[receivedBndl](type = cPacket);
```

For nodes:

```
@signal[sentBndl](type = cPacket);
```

As each actual sent/received packet is now emitted to their sending/receiving module (and anything above them), you can install a statistic in the top-level module and combine them into a single statistic:

```
@statistic[deliveryratio](source=count(receivedBndl)/count(sentBndl); record=last);
```

This last line will install two signal listeners on the top level module and the statistics will calculate the value each and every time any module generates or receives a packet anywhere in the network.

Comment: So, if i understand well what are you saying to me, i have to emit signals from all senders and receivers modules to a global module that will process these statistics, than this later will emit a new signal to itself in order to draw statistics and delivery ratio versus time with the use of vector.

Comment: also, what is the difference between sum and count, it is a little bit confusing ? Thanks,

Comment: No, you don't have to send all signals to the a top level module. Each signal can be emitted to the actual module. I was suggesting to *attach the statistics* to the top level module. Signals emitted to a module are automatically delivered to the module AND to all its parent module in OMNeT++. This means by default the top level network module receives ALL of the signals sent to any module in the network. You don'T hav eto modify the actual emit() code, just gather the statistics at the top level. (As for COUNT vs SUM, you are right, that was misleading and I have corrected the answer)

Comment: Added some more info how to create derived statistics.